# Disk drive in ubuntu full?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

How do i partition disk drive in Ubuntu to dual boot windows 10 but its already full from installation and resize it so i can dual boot it?

Every video i watch of it starts with windows 10 first and anywhere i look it does and I've tried virtual box its runs really slow because of my hardware its mostly my graphics card fault I've got 8 GB of RAM 2x Intel Core 2 CPU 6400 @ 2.13GHz and a nvidia gefore 310 512 MB graphics card.

Comment: Windows must be installed _first_ in a dual boot system. Do you have Windows 10 installed already?  If so, back up your Ubuntu data, for you will need to wipe away the entire drive before the Windows install. The Ubuntu install must follow the Windows install.

Comment: Related possible duplicae: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011645/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have multiple kernels taking up space you need.

`df -h` run from within a terminal window shows your space on all partitions.

To see all kernels, do `dpkg -l linux-image*`

You can remove multiple old kernels at once with a command like
`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.32-{21,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44}-server`  (substitute your numbers based on what you find with dpkg) but be very careful not to remove the current kernel, nor the latest kernel!

`uname -r` shows you what you are currently using.

`sudo apt-get autoremove` is good to run after removing old kernels as it removes obsolete dependencies.